# Distance between two Aruco Markers in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, robotics, aruco

I am trying to calculate the distance between two Aruco markers in Python. I have code that can calculate the pose of one marker but I am not sure how to move from there. Is there anyone that has done something similar or can point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the distance between the markers by calculating the distance between the corners of the detected markers. 
The following will give you the corners and the co-ordinates of that corner.

```
corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints = aruco.detectMarkers(gray, aruco_dict, parameters=arucoParameters)
x1 = int (corners[0][0][0][0]) 
y1 = int (corners[0][0][0][1])
```

Similarly you can find the co-ordinates of the corner of the other marker (x2,y2).

```
import math  
def calculateDistance(x1,y1,x2,y2):  
     dist = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)  
     return dist  
print calculateDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

This code will give the distance between the two corners

Comment: How can I get the corners of the ids? If it is detecting multiple markers I can't seem to get the corner values of each one.

Comment: corners is a numpy array. Hence corners[0] gives you the first markers corners. For the next one, use corners[1] and so on.